# Making XCode project inherit child project settings

Tags: ios, xcode, linker, shared-libraries

I have a number of XCode projects which are libraries for a game (Core, Renderer, IO, etc).  These library projects have their own library dependencies, e.g. Renderer relies on OpenGL.  Whenever I add these projects to a parent project I need to re-add the library dependencies to the parent in order to link correctly (e.g. I have to add Opengl libs to the game project even though the Renderer library already specifies it).

Is there a way I can set the parent project to automatically link against the libs in the child projects?

Thanks
Allan

Comment: Use `Cocopods` maybe.